# Spring Android Get Request implementation : Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type and content type

Tags: android, spring, web-services, resttemplate

I am trying to implement Android spring get request. When I run the application I am getting following error.

> Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
>   response type [com.example.userprofiledemo.UserProfile] and content
>   type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]

**Respose Body contains nested class and List of classes, Respose xml looks like this:**

```
<UserProfile xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Address>Degisim  A Blok Asmakat</Address>
<City>Adana</City>

<UserBookingInfo>
    <ArrivalDate>2012-01-03T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
    <CourseTypeCode>ILS</CourseTypeCode>
</UserBookingInfo>

<UserPhotoList>
  <UserPhoto> 
    <LikeCount>10</LikeCount>
    <UserPhotoId>123</UserPhotoId>
  </UserPhoto>

   <UserPhoto> 
    <LikeCount>11</LikeCount>
    <UserPhotoId>129</UserPhotoId>
  </UserPhoto>

  <UserPhoto> 
    <LikeCount>11</LikeCount>
    <UserPhotoId>129</UserPhotoId>
  </UserPhoto>
</UserPhotoList>

</UserProfile>
```

**Note :-**

1. `UserProfile(Userprofile.java)` is Root Class or Node
2. `UserBookingInfo(UserBookingInfo.java)` is element in `UserProfile`.
3. `UserPhoteList(UserPhoteList.java)` is a List of `UserPhotos(UserPhote.java)` in `UsersProfile`

**This is what I am doing to parse response using Spring Android.**

**My REST client PopulatePojo.java**

```
public class PopulatePojo {

public UserProfile GetUserProfile() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);


    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    FormHttpMessageConverter msgConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);


    UserProfile userProfile = null;
    try {
        userProfile = restTemplate.getForObject(url, UserProfile.class);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return userProfile;
}
}
```

**Bean Class UserProfile.java**

```
@Root
public class UserProfile {

@Element(name = "Address", required = false)
private String address;

      @Element(name="City",required=false)
private String city;

      @Element(name="UserBookingInfo",required=false)
private UserBookingInfo userBookingInfo;

      @Element(name = "UserPhotoList")
private UserPhotoList userPhotoList;

      public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

      public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

      public UserBookingInfo getUserBookingInfo() {
    return userBookingInfo;
}

public void setUserBookingInfo(UserBookingInfo userBookingInfo) {
    this.userBookingInfo = userBookingInfo;
}

     public UserPhotoList getUserPhotoList() {
    return userPhotoList;
}

public void setUserPhotoList(UserPhotoList userPhotoList) {
    this.userPhotoList = userPhotoList;
}



}
```

**Bean class UserBookingInfo.java**

```
public class UserBookingInfo {

@Element(name="ArrivalDate",required=false)
private String arrivalDate;

@Element(name="CourseTypeCode",required=false)
private String courseTypeCode;

      public String getArrivalDate() {
    return arrivalDate;
}

public void setArrivalDate(String arrivalDate) {
    this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
}

public String getCourseTypeCode() {
    return courseTypeCode;
}

public void setCourseTypeCode(String courseTypeCode) {
    this.courseTypeCode = courseTypeCode;
}
 }
```

**Bean class which List of UserPhotoList(UserPhotoList.java)**

```
@Root(name="UserPhotoList")
public class UserPhotoList {

@ElementList(inline=true,entry="UserPhoto")
private List<UserPhoto> userPhotos;

public List<UserPhoto> getUserPhotos() {
    return userPhotos;
}

public void setUserPhotos(List<UserPhoto> userPhotos) {
    this.userPhotos = userPhotos;
}
```

}

**Bean Class for UserPhoto.java**

```
@Root
public class UserPhoto {

@Element(name = "LikeCount", required = false)
private String likeCount;

      @Element(name = "UserPhotoId ", required = false)
private String userPhotoId ;

      public String getLikeCount() {
    return likeCount;
}

public void setLikeCount(String likeCount) {
    this.likeCount = likeCount;
}

      public String getUserPhotoId() {
    return userPhotoId;
}

public void setUserPhotoId(String userPhotoId) {
    this.userPhotoId = userPhotoId;
}     

  }
```

Please let me where I am doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

**It works fine when I use simpleframe and Httpget**

**Below is working code without using RestTemplate**

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
                          @Override
        public void run() {

            String xmlData = retrieve(url);
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();

            Reader reader = new StringReader(xmlData);
            try {
                UserProfile profile = serializer.read     (UserProfile.class,
                        reader, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occured",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

}
        }).start();

public String retrieve(String url) {

```
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        if (getResponseEntity != null) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;

}
```

**How Can I achive the same thing using RestTemplete**

**I struck with problem from couple of days,Any help greately appricated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server returns an XML content but says it returns HTML content (content type is `text/html` according to the error message) and thus the parsing failed. You need to make sure your server returns something like `text/xml` and also that you have the correct converters in you rest template object.

**Edit:** Try to add this message converter. **Put it first (before `StringHttpMessageConverter` and `SourceHttpMessageConverter`)**

```
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
messageConverters .add(jaxbMessageConverter);
```

Comment: Good Obserrvation ,Thanks for feedback.I dont have control over what sever returns.Could you suggeste me any work arround on client side.                                                               I can able to achive(parse) the same using simpleFramework and through Httpget but I have this problem only using RestTemplate.                                                       I update my question with working code which using simpleFramework  but no RestTemplate.

Comment: What happens if you call the url through the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your follow up and suggestion,I added your code it leads to class not found error (Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.class) I added particular jar to fix, it lead me to some other problem,It went on.                                                                 But your first suggestion was right, its the problem with server end,Finally server guys fixed there problem after discussion with them, now every thing is working fine without any changes form my end.I would like to try alternate solution which you mentioned in your EDIT sometime(one more time). Thanks you once again.